# angular-google-maps getting GEO location from mouse click

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, geolocation

I am using the library angular-google-maps from http://angular-google-maps.org/. I am able to get most everything to work. What I am currently banging my head against is to get the "click" event to work on the map to give me the GEO location of where I clicked. Currently it's not even registering that I am clicking on the map.

Here is my partial:

```
<google-map 
    center="map.center"
    zoom="map.zoom"
    draggable='true'
    >


</google-map>
```

and here is the controller:

```
    // Create Map
    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 40.296755,
            longitude: -111.696415
        },
        zoom: 13,
        events: {
            click: function (mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                alert("hola?");
            }
        }

    };
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the event to the map, you need to attach an associative array (object) to the events attribute of the  directive:

```
<google-map events="$scope.events" .... ></google-map>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.events = {"click" : function () { console.log('woo-hoo') })
```

Comment: I do apologies. Let me take that part out. It's not for a marker. I want it on the entire map.

Comment: Got it.  You need to define the events object you have in your controller as an attribute in your google-map directive.  Like this:    <google-map center="map.center" events="map.events"....></google-map>

Comment: Perfect. Thats what I needed. If you post this as an answer I can select it as the solution.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I haven't heard of angular-google-maps before, so looking forward to playing around with it.  I changed the answer above to reflect the changes.

Comment: BTW I just subscribed to angular-google-maps as a tag. So I should be able to see these questions more often now.